# DNS using BIND with Subdomains - Multiple Servers and Hosting Accounts

Tags: linux, dns, bind

Hopefully someone can help clarify this.

I have a domain ie example.com registered with Go Daddy. I host the website with TSOHost so in my domain configuration, I have set the following NS records.

Nameserver 1: ns1.tsohost.co.uk

Nameserver 2: ns2.tsohost.co.uk

I am now able to serve the website both www and non www from this hosting package. I simply have an A record for example.com and a CNAME for www.example.com to point to example.com (this is being configured in the cpanel Advanced DNS Zone Editor). So now we have the website showing as expected and required.

I would also like to setup a kind of DDNS service using a different server entirely, (this will hold DNS records that I will create on the fly using a Radius database).

So I want to use the subdomain ddns.example.com for this DDNS service, ie bob.ddns.example.com for Bob (so that when I ping bob.ddn.example.com, I can alter the IP to 8.8.8. say). In Cpanel I have an A record for ddns.example.com and an A record for *.ddns.example.com to point to my server that will manage this, for example 85.214.214.214.

I have installed Bind on the server (currently using a digital ocean server for this, to which I have added ddns.exmaple.com as an A record to the droplet and *.ddns.example.com also), I have created a zone for ddns.example.com, within this I have set the ns record as the digital ocean details.

I have then added the following to my file /var/named/ddns.example.com.hosts

```
$ttl 38400
ddns.example.com.    IN      SOA     ns1.digitalocean.com. jon@example.com. (
                1414575123
                10800
                3600
                604800
                38400 )
ddns.example.com.    IN      NS      ns1.digitalocean.com.
bob.ddns.example.com.        IN      A       8.8.8.8
```

When I ping bob.ddns.example.com on the server with bind installed I get 8.8.8.8, but when pinging for anywhere else I get the bind server IP.

Can I ask if what I am doing is possible ie, going from godaddy to tso, to another server and if so what NS records should I specify for bind? or is there something in the named config I need to change, I have set the following options in named.conf in an attempt to solve this issue.

```
listen-on port 53 { any; };
listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };
allow-query     { any; };
recursion yes;
```

I am aware that recursion may leave me open to DOS attacks and I intend to turn this to no eventually, but for the moment during testing I have left this to yes.

Any help or information would be greatly appreciated, I have been trying different variations of zone files etc without success, I am really though unsure as to if I am going in the right direction.

Hopefully I have made sense, but any further info I can provide, please let me know.

Comment: You should be able to delegate subdomains as may times as you need. I'm not sure I've understood situation outlined in the question exactly but it seems from your explanation that you have the NS record delegating ddns.example.com to ns1.digitalocean.com in the wrong place. It needs to be in the zone served by ns1.tsohost.co.uk not ns1.digitalocean.com.

Comment: @SamGreenhalgh It seems that I need to create custom name servers and delegate the subdomain to these servers at Godaddy.If you set master NS records for the whole domain it seems you cannot then split from here and create further ns records for a subdomian.This may be specifically related to TSO Host as they do not offer the ability to create ns records only A or CNAME.I have solved the situation with another domain,but the I cannot change the ns servers for the main domain as I don't disruption. By all means put your comment as an answer and I will award the bounty. Shame to see it wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first question would be - Are you sure you've updated the Registrar with this server as the DNS nameserver for this domain?

```
Use nslookup to find out:

# nslookup
> set querytype=NS
> server 4.2.2.1   (a DNS server on the Internet)
> ddns.example.com.   (a closing dot helps avoid lookups using preferred search domains.)
```

and confirm that the Internet knows who to communicate with, and that your NS host is authoritative for the domain.

Next would be - Do you have any other nameservers up to "answer" for that subdomain, causing other problems?

BTW - glad to hear you fixed this issue!